# Grouping multiple data in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have this table in my oracle db
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbxAZ.png)

is there some way I can perform the grouping in SQL? so that the returned data is something like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcXPB.png)

Thank you

Comment: Please don't upload images. Provide both sample data and expected outcome as tables to allow people to replicate your question. Please also explain what you tried so far and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Oracle you can use:

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT qc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY qc) AS qc,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT packing, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY packing)
         AS packing,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT delivering, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY delivering)
         AS delivering
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY product_id
```

However, in Oracle 11, `LISTAGG` does not support the `DISTINCT` keyword and you would either need to pre-process the input to remove duplicates or to post-process the aggregated string:

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       REPLACE(
         TRIM(
           BOTH ',' FROM
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             ',' || LISTAGG(qc, ',,') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY qc) || ',',
             '(,.*?,)\1+',
             '\1'
           )
         ),
         ',,',
         ','
       )AS qc,
       REPLACE(
         TRIM(
           BOTH ',' FROM
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             ',' || LISTAGG(packing, ',,') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY packing) || ',',
             '(,.*?,)\1+',
             '\1'
           )
         ),
         ',,',
         ','
       )AS packing,
       REPLACE(
         TRIM(
           BOTH ',' FROM
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             ',' || LISTAGG(delivering, ',,') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY delivering) || ',',
             '(,.*?,)\1+',
             '\1'
           )
         ),
         ',,',
         ','
       )AS delivering
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY product_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( product_id, qc, packing, delivering ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'A', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', 'C', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', 'B', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', 'D', 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output (for compliant versions):

| PRODUCT_ID | QC | PACKING | DELIVERING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A,B | C |
| 2 | A | C | C |
| 3 | A | B,D | D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l9R8URNa)